# C# FtpWebRequest set interface

Tags: c#, ftp

I have many network interfaces on my computer(including WiFi, Ethernet).
If I want to set a specific network interface to use `FtpWebRequest`,
is it possible? Or the Windows will pick a correct interface?
Here is my code.

```
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + targetIP + ":2121/project.zip");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.Timeout = 20 * 1000;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 20 * 1000;


            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");

            using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(p))
            using (var outputStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                int totalReadBytesCount = 0;
                int readBytesCount;
                while ((readBytesCount = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytesCount);
                    totalReadBytesCount += readBytesCount;
                    Transfer.transfer[0].transferLength += totalReadBytesCount;

                    double progress = (double)Transfer.transfer[0].transferLength / Transfer.transfer[0].totalLength;
                    e.Window.Message = CommonResource.Exporting_String + " " + Math.Round(progress * 100) + "%";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Wifi and Ethernet are protocols in low layers (physical) of the 7 layers model while ftp is a protocol that comes in the higher layers (application). ftp can run on both it depends to which one you are connected. read more here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

Comment: Thanks! I have read the OSI model. The situation is possible that the WiFi and the Ethernet is both connected but in different LAN, and they have their own IP address. So, Windows will automatically determine which to use a network interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible by using the `ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate`:

```
 public static void ExecuteRequest()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }

    private static IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
    {
        // We want to make sure we try everything for the request to pass.
        IPEndPoint defaultEndPoint = null;
        foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            // Loop through all interfaces, check if the current interface is 'Up' (ready to transmit) first.
            if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                bool returnIP = false;
                //if (networkInterface.Id == "MyAdapter")
                //if (networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                if (networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
                {
                    // If the interface matches our wishes, tell the next block of code to return the (if) found matching IP
                    returnIP = true;
                }

                if (returnIP || defaultEndPoint == null)
                {
                    // Loop through the UnicastAddresses assigned to this interface.
                    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in networkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        // Check if any of the addresses is IPv4
                        if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            // If so, create ourselves a new IPEndPoint and if needed return it.
                            defaultEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip.Address, 0);
                            if (returnIP)
                            {
                                return defaultEndPoint;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (defaultEndPoint == null)
        {
            // Optional:
            //throw new NotSupportedException("A valid internet connection is required for this program to run.");
        }
        return defaultEndPoint;    
    }
```

I've used this for webrequests (as shown) but for `FTPWebRequest` it will work too. Note that the callback method will always try to return an adapter, even if the one you are looking for is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible by setting ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate Property

Check this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms144146%28en-us,vs.80%29.aspx

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + targetIP + ":2121/project.zip");
request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = delegate
{
      return new IPEndPoint(IP, PORT);
};
```